# How to overwrite local stable version artifacts using publishLocal?

Tags: sbt

I've got several projects. I use `publishLocal` to update the local repository. Sometimes I'm working on a couple of them in parallel and I don't want to keep updating the version numbers.

So I use `publishLocal` that works fine, but it issues this warning

```
[warn]  This usage is deprecated and will be removed in sbt 1.0.
[warn] Attempting to overwrite /home/tim/.ivy2/local/com.optrak/vrpmodel_2.11/0.8.3/ivys/ivy.xml.sha1
```

So presumably I'm supposed to use something else. But what?

Comment: Could you share what the dependent projects are? Are they all belong to a single application unit? What's the level of dependency between them? You could use `ProjectRef` instead.

Comment: The projects are all within the same family of an application but are split because, for example, some need akka and some don't. Some will be used on android. In the immediate set there is a directed graph of relationships - i.e. no cyclic dependencies. And they all sit in the sam git repo (not sure if that makes any difference) and on disk are in child directories of the same (empty) parent.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It all begins as [a workaround for #1156](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/ivy/src/main/scala/sbt/ConvertResolver.scala#L140-L148) that says (in [#1156](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1156)):

> Basically, as of sbt 0.13.2 you can no longer republish a release if
>   it already exists. This is quite a dangerous thing to do because it
>   leads to broken caches all over. Only -SNAPSHOTs are allowed to be
>   republished.

It means that you `publishLocal` a stable version not `SNAPSHOT` and the preferred option is to **not** overwrite stable versions.

As a workaround you can use `isSnapshot := true` as confirmed in [@jsuereth's comment](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1156#issuecomment-43512022):

> isSnapshot, currently, only denotes that the build can overwrite
>   previous values.

I confirmed it myself, too, with the following `build.sbt`:

```
version := "1.0.0"
```

See the session:

```
➜  stable-version-published-twice  xsbt
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/java8/Contents/Home
SBT_OPTS= -Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins/}global-plugins...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to stable-version-published-twice (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/stable-version-published-twice/)
> show version
[info] 1.0.0
```

As you may have noticed the project is at `1.0.0` version. Here goes the first `publishLocal`.

```
> publishLocal
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/stable-version-published-twice/}stable-version-published-twice...
[info] Packaging /Users/jacek/sandbox/stable-version-published-twice/target/scala-2.10/stable-version-published-twice_2.10-1.0.0-sources.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Wrote /Users/jacek/sandbox/stable-version-published-twice/target/scala-2.10/stable-version-published-twice_2.10-1.0.0.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] :: delivering :: default#stable-version-published-twice_2.10;1.0.0 :: 1.0.0 :: release :: Sun Sep 28 22:46:10 CEST 2014
[info]  delivering ivy file to /Users/jacek/sandbox/stable-version-published-twice/target/scala-2.10/ivy-1.0.0.xml
[info] Packaging /Users/jacek/sandbox/stable-version-published-twice/target/scala-2.10/stable-version-published-twice_2.10-1.0.0-javadoc.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Packaging /Users/jacek/sandbox/stable-version-published-twice/target/scala-2.10/stable-version-published-twice_2.10-1.0.0.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info]  published stable-version-published-twice_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/poms/stable-version-published-twice_2.10.pom
[info]  published stable-version-published-twice_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/jars/stable-version-published-twice_2.10.jar
[info]  published stable-version-published-twice_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/srcs/stable-version-published-twice_2.10-sources.jar
[info]  published stable-version-published-twice_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/docs/stable-version-published-twice_2.10-javadoc.jar
[info]  published ivy to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Sep 28, 2014 10:46:10 PM
```

It went fine (as expected). Here goes the other `publishLocal` (that should succeed with warnings - `This usage is deprecated and will be removed in sbt 1.0.` - since we're republishing the stable version).

```
> publishLocal
[info] Wrote /Users/jacek/sandbox/stable-version-published-twice/target/scala-2.10/stable-version-published-twice_2.10-1.0.0.pom
[info] :: delivering :: default#stable-version-published-twice_2.10;1.0.0 :: 1.0.0 :: release :: Sun Sep 28 22:46:18 CEST 2014
[info]  delivering ivy file to /Users/jacek/sandbox/stable-version-published-twice/target/scala-2.10/ivy-1.0.0.xml
[warn] Attempting to overwrite /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/poms/stable-version-published-twice_2.10.pom
[warn]  This usage is deprecated and will be removed in sbt 1.0.
[warn] Attempting to overwrite /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/poms/stable-version-published-twice_2.10.pom.sha1
[warn]  This usage is deprecated and will be removed in sbt 1.0.
[warn] Attempting to overwrite /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/poms/stable-version-published-twice_2.10.pom.md5
[warn]  This usage is deprecated and will be removed in sbt 1.0.
[info]  published stable-version-published-twice_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/poms/stable-version-published-twice_2.10.pom
[warn] Attempting to overwrite /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/jars/stable-version-published-twice_2.10.jar
[warn]  This usage is deprecated and will be removed in sbt 1.0.
[warn] Attempting to overwrite /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/jars/stable-version-published-twice_2.10.jar.sha1
[warn]  This usage is deprecated and will be removed in sbt 1.0.
[warn] Attempting to overwrite /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/jars/stable-version-published-twice_2.10.jar.md5
[warn]  This usage is deprecated and will be removed in sbt 1.0.
[info]  published stable-version-published-twice_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/jars/stable-version-published-twice_2.10.jar
[warn] Attempting to overwrite /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/srcs/stable-version-published-twice_2.10-sources.jar
[warn]  This usage is deprecated and will be removed in sbt 1.0.
[warn] Attempting to overwrite /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/srcs/stable-version-published-twice_2.10-sources.jar.sha1
[warn]  This usage is deprecated and will be removed in sbt 1.0.
[warn] Attempting to overwrite /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/srcs/stable-version-published-twice_2.10-sources.jar.md5
[warn]  This usage is deprecated and will be removed in sbt 1.0.
[info]  published stable-version-published-twice_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/srcs/stable-version-published-twice_2.10-sources.jar
[warn] Attempting to overwrite /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/docs/stable-version-published-twice_2.10-javadoc.jar
[warn]  This usage is deprecated and will be removed in sbt 1.0.
[warn] Attempting to overwrite /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/docs/stable-version-published-twice_2.10-javadoc.jar.sha1
[warn]  This usage is deprecated and will be removed in sbt 1.0.
[warn] Attempting to overwrite /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/docs/stable-version-published-twice_2.10-javadoc.jar.md5
[warn]  This usage is deprecated and will be removed in sbt 1.0.
[info]  published stable-version-published-twice_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/docs/stable-version-published-twice_2.10-javadoc.jar
[warn] Attempting to overwrite /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn]  This usage is deprecated and will be removed in sbt 1.0.
[warn] Attempting to overwrite /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml.sha1
[warn]  This usage is deprecated and will be removed in sbt 1.0.
[warn] Attempting to overwrite /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml.md5
[warn]  This usage is deprecated and will be removed in sbt 1.0.
[info]  published ivy to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Sep 28, 2014 10:46:18 PM
```

That went as expected. The warnings are there.

Let's set `isSnapshot` to `true` to denote the stable version as *changing*.

**NOTE** I wouldn't recommend it, though, since some other code in the build could be relying on a proper `isSnapshot` to be `false` for `1.0.0`.

```
> set isSnapshot := true
[info] Defining *:isSnapshot
[info] The new value will be used by *:deliverLocalConfiguration, *:publishConfiguration and 1 others.
[info]  Run `last` for details.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to stable-version-published-twice (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/stable-version-published-twice/)
```

Let's `publishLocal` the stable version again.

```
> publishLocal
[info] Wrote /Users/jacek/sandbox/stable-version-published-twice/target/scala-2.10/stable-version-published-twice_2.10-1.0.0.pom
[info] :: delivering :: default#stable-version-published-twice_2.10;1.0.0 :: 1.0.0 :: integration :: Sun Sep 28 22:46:44 CEST 2014
[info]  delivering ivy file to /Users/jacek/sandbox/stable-version-published-twice/target/scala-2.10/ivy-1.0.0.xml
[info]  published stable-version-published-twice_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/poms/stable-version-published-twice_2.10.pom
[info]  published stable-version-published-twice_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/jars/stable-version-published-twice_2.10.jar
[info]  published stable-version-published-twice_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/srcs/stable-version-published-twice_2.10-sources.jar
[info]  published stable-version-published-twice_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/docs/stable-version-published-twice_2.10-javadoc.jar
[info]  published ivy to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Sep 28, 2014 10:46:44 PM
```

It went without warnings. Let's try `publishLocal` out again.

```
> publishLocal
[info] Wrote /Users/jacek/sandbox/stable-version-published-twice/target/scala-2.10/stable-version-published-twice_2.10-1.0.0.pom
[info] :: delivering :: default#stable-version-published-twice_2.10;1.0.0 :: 1.0.0 :: integration :: Sun Sep 28 22:46:46 CEST 2014
[info]  delivering ivy file to /Users/jacek/sandbox/stable-version-published-twice/target/scala-2.10/ivy-1.0.0.xml
[info]  published stable-version-published-twice_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/poms/stable-version-published-twice_2.10.pom
[info]  published stable-version-published-twice_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/jars/stable-version-published-twice_2.10.jar
[info]  published stable-version-published-twice_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/srcs/stable-version-published-twice_2.10-sources.jar
[info]  published stable-version-published-twice_2.10 to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/docs/stable-version-published-twice_2.10-javadoc.jar
[info]  published ivy to /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/default/stable-version-published-twice_2.10/1.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Sep 28, 2014 10:46:46 PM
```

Again, no warnings - it works as advertised.

Comment: thanks, needs `set isSnapshot in ThisBuild := true` for multi project build.